How Swap on Jupiter via Jito tips?
jupiter = Jupiter(
async_client=solana_client,
keypair=sender,
)
token_mint = "T1oYbAejEESrZLtSAjumAXhzFqZGNxQ4kVN9vPUoxMv"  # Mint адрес токена, который вы хотите купить
amount_in_sol = 0.01  # Количество SOL, которое вы хотите потратить на покупку токена
LAMPORTS_PER_SOL = 1_000_000_000  # 1 SOL = 1,000,000,000 lamports
amount_in_lamports = int(amount_in_sol * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL)

# Выполнение свопа через Jupiter
transaction_data = await jupiter.swap(
    input_mint="So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",  # WSOL
    output_mint=token_mint,
    amount=amount_in_lamports,
    slippage_bps=50,  # 0.5% slippage
)

recent_blockhash = await solana_client.get_latest_blockhash()

versioned_tx = VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(transaction_data))

# Получаем инструкции из versioned_tx
instructions = list(versioned_tx.message.instructions)

# Создаем Jito tip инструкцию
jito_tip_account = Pubkey.from_string(sdk.get_random_tip_account())
jito_tip = transfer(
    TransferParams(
        from_pubkey=sender.pubkey(),
        to_pubkey=jito_tip_account,
        lamports=1000
    )
)

# Добавляем Jito tip к инструкциям
instructions.append(jito_tip)

# Создаем новую транзакцию с обновленными инструкциями
transaction = Transaction.new_with_payer(
    instructions=instructions,
    payer=sender.pubkey()
)

# Подписываем транзакцию
transaction.sign([sender], recent_blockhash.value.blockhash)

# Отправка транзакции через Jito
serialized_transaction = base58.b58encode(bytes(transaction)).decode('ascii')
response = sdk.send_txn(params=serialized_transaction, bundleOnly=True)

if response['success']:
    print(f"Full Jito SDK response: {response}")
    signature_str = response['data']['result']
    print(f"Transaction signature: {signature_str}")

    finalized = await check_transaction_status(solana_client, signature_str)

    if finalized:
        print("Transaction has been finalized.")
        solscan_url = f"https://solscan.io/tx/{signature_str}"
        print(f"View transaction details on Solscan: {solscan_url}")
    else:
        print("Transaction was not finalized within the expected time.")
else:
    print(f"Error sending transaction: {response['error']}")

transaction = Transaction.new_with_payer(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument 'instructions': 'CompiledInstruction' object cannot be converted to 'Instruction'
